# Swift3 Extension on "Any?" -ish class?

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

Shorter explanation:

You often want to extend on "target" ... and targets are usually `Any?`. But you can't have an extension on `Any`. How to do it?

---

Consider this,

```
extension UIViewController {    
    func add(tap v:UIView, _ action:Selector) {
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
        v.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
}
```

Excellent, you can now...

```
self.tap(redButton, #selector(clickedRedButton))
```

... in any view controller.

But you can do the same thing to just about any target.

So, to use the extension on a UITableViewCell say, you have to also have....

```
extension UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        func add(tap v:UIView, _ action:Selector) {
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
        v.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
}
```

The target argument of UITapGestureRecognizer is actually `Any?`

But, you can not do this ...

```
extension Any {
```

What's the solution?  How to make an extension that will work on the `Any?`, as for example in the first argument of `UITapGestureRecognizer` ?

Or as Conner'c comment suggests, is there a way to:

```
extension  UIViewController or UIView {
```

rather than copying and pasting it twice?

Comment: This is very roundabout. Any function that just calls its parameter's function (`addGestureRecognizer`) could be tacked on to any extension. The fact that you want to be able to add a gesture recognizer from anywhere other than a controller or a view is not a good design decision.

Comment: hi @ConnorNeville - sure, as you say either a **controller or a view**.  So, currently I need to have the two extensions - one for a controller and one for a view.  So, how to generalize that? Having only one extension?

Comment: It's a very straightforward idea that you might want to extend on a "target" ... and targets are usually `Any?`.  How to do it?

Comment: the entire concept seems a bit clumsy... so, why would you need to do such overcomplicated thing at the first place? I mean, what is the _bigger_ problem which you'd like to eliminate or resolve by making your life harder?

Comment: @holex, every single extension is "useless" - and you could eliminate every single extension by just writing it out at length.  Nature of Swift is that it's Swift - you can "rewrite" the language so it's swifter.

Comment: @JoeBlow, I just asked innocently that what kinda problem you'd like to resolve because usually developers are making patterns _on definite purpose_, and your idea seemingly does not seem to actually simplify anything; and doing something _just for a sake of doing_ only makes not too much sense (to me, at least) :) so, in such perspective you could've overloaded a few operators randomly as well to achive something similar, based on the simple fact: _Swift_ allows that as well... :)

Comment: @JoeBlow The problem I see is that you are putting helper methods to wrong places. You should be adding the `tap` method to `UIView`, with parameters `target` and `selector`, not to `UIViewController` with `view` and `selector`. From architecture point of view you are making strange things.

Comment: Hi @Sulthan, say you're in view controller V, you're adding a call to indeed a function in V - it's the natural place to extend on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Any" is adhered to (passively) by every struct/class. An extension to Any would add that functionality to every single type in the language and your code. This isn't currently possible, and I doubt it ever would be (or should be).

Anyway, here are a few ways to solve this problem.

My preference is a protocol extension that adds the functionality:

```
protocol TapGestureAddable {
    func addTapGestureRecognizer(to view: UIView, with action: Selector) -> UITapGestureRecognizer
}

extension TapGestureAddable {
    func addTapGestureRecognizer(to view: UIView, with action: Selector) -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        return recognizer
    }
}

extension UIViewController: TapGestureAddable { }
extension UIView: TapGestureAddable { }
```

This forces you to knowingly *choose* to add the functionality to a given class, (a good thing IMO) without having to duplicate any meaningful code.

Possibly a better option would be to make this logic an extension of UIView instead:

```
extension UIView {

    func addTapGestureRecognizer(with responder: Any, for action: Selector)  -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: responder, action: action)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        return recognizer
    }

    func addTapGestureRecognizer(with action: Selector)  -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        return recognizer
    }
}
```

Otherwise, just make a global function:

```
func addTapGestureRecognizer(to view: UIView, with responder: Any, for action: Selector) -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: responder, action: action)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    return recognizer
}
```

Comment: great thinking all round!

Answer (score 2):

`Any` isn't a class in the way that `NSObject` is.  It is merely a keyword that indicates to the Swift compiler that a variable/constant/parameter may refer to any object or struct instance, so it isn't possible to extend `Any`.

If you consider what you are trying to do, you would have a subtle difference between your two extensions anyway;

- The `UIViewController` extension needs to accept a target view (your `v`) parameter
- While, for a `UIView` extension, you don't need `v` as this will be `self`; it doesn't make sense to install a gesture recogniser on some other `UIView`.
- For the `UIView` extension, you may want to specify a different target for the selector.
- You don't add a gesture recogniser to the UIViewController, so it doesn't make, semantically, to extend `UIViewController` in this way.

So, to me, it seems that the logical extension looks somthing like:

```
extension UIView {
    func add(_ action:Selector,tapHandler target:Any = self) {
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: action)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
}
```

Now, in a `UIViewController` you can say something like:

```
self.redButton.add(Selector(("handleTap")), tapHandler: self)
```

While in a `UIView` subclass you can say:

```
self.add(Selector(("handleTap")))
```

Comment: ( "While, for a UIView extension, you don't need v as this will be self; it doesn't make sense to install a gesture recogniser on some other UIView" ... on a subview is common.)

Comment: So, add it on the sub view. My point is, it is the target for the action rather than the view where you add the gesture recognizer that you need to provide